# Unable to populate data into table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is Swift 4.
I was not able to populate the data (in the information array) into the table view.
I am expecting the strings "Name", "Date of Birth", "Gender", "Phone", "Email" to show up in the table view but nothing is showing up.

I have entered "ProfileInfo" as my tableViewCell identifier.

Thanks.

```
let information = ["Name", "Date of Birth", "Gender", "Phone", "Email"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return information.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProfileInfo", for: indexPath) as! OTProfileTableViewCell
        cell.label.text = information[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

[image: No data is being populated into table view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things the OP didn't include. I assume you are using a `UIViewController` subclass with a `UITableView` as a subview (since there is another view above the table and this is not as straightforward with a `UITableViewController`).

Please try the following if they are not already being done:

1. Make sure your view controller is assigned as the  `tableView.dataSource`. You can set this in `viewDidLoad` or in interface builder.
2. Declare conformance to the UITableViewDataSource protocol in your view controller. Preferably in an extension that contains implementation of all of the required methods of the protocol.

Is `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` being called and is the cell you are grabbing the correct type? Use a breakpoint in this method to inspect. If the breakpoint isn't hit you are likely not setting the data source of the table properly.

Set a breakpoint in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` as well. This method should always be executed (as long as you have at least 1section).